# Update my jailbroken iPhone 4 iOS 4.2.1 to iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, software-update

I'm new to this but I had my phone jailbroken years ago and they told me I had to stay under Apple's radar so I never tried to get it updated. Now I can barely use any of my apps, for instance I can't FaceTime at all any more. Can someone provide step by step instructions on how to update my phone?

Answer (score 1):

1. Back up your iPhone with iTunes.
2. Restore your iPhone with iTunes.

   If you want your phone jailbroken with iOS 7.1.2, jailbreak it at this point.
3. Restore your iPhone from backup.

Comment: Would you suggest me to do the backup overnight because I know I wont be able to use my phone while Im doing the backup and restore and people have told me since Im on ios 4.2.1 its gonna take forever for the whole process

Comment: @Vanessa You can use your phone whilst it's doing the backup AFAIK, but you won't be able to during the restore. The version of iOS doesn't make a difference on how long the process takes—it's how much content you have on your device that makes the difference.

Comment: Oh ok.. Last question. Am I suppose to use Pangu to re-jailbreak it?

Comment: @Vanessa [Yes](http://en.7.pangu.io/)